# Изъяснительное или условное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, сослагательное-наклонение

Не могли бы Вы помочь мне разобраться с этим предложением пожалуйста:

> *И теперь представь себе, **что Ленин родился бы** в Америке.*

Сомневаюсь как правильно его интерпретировать:

a) как изъяснительное предложение с сослагательным наклонением; при этом частица БЫ находится на дистанции от ЧТО;

b) как неполное условное предложение - если развернуть, можно получить "И теперь представь себе, что было бы, если бы Ленин родился в Америке."

Что Вы считаете здесь правильно?

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Семантика  глагола ***представить*** уже  связана с ирреальной действительностью, поэтому в большинстве случаев частица БЫ в этом случае не пишется. Вообразить можно любую ситуацию, например: **"Представь, что весь метрополитен — это человеческий организм".**

Но всё-таки частица БЫ используется в таких предложениях, где интерес вызывает не только предполагаемый факт, **а прежде всего  связанные с ним последствия событий**: **Ты только представь, что было бы, если бы в лагере Шмидта была современная телеустановка!**

И действительно, "что было бы" можно опустить, и тогда получаем:Ты только представь,  если бы в лагере Шмидта была современная телеустановка!

Примерно та же ситуация с  историческим лицом:

**И теперь представь себе, что** (было бы, если) **Ленин родился бы в Америке.** По структуре это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, родился бы - форма сослагательного наклонения.

Другие примеры с частицей БЫ (здесь она тоже не кажется лишней):

Только представь, что я бы всю жизнь, как та Шуламита, (ходила) в банном халате...

Представь, что тебе бы понадобилось кого-то убрать, неужели ты сам стал бы марать руки?

Представьте, что бы из этого получилось при сегодняшних дорогах и топливных проблемах.

Comment: Arina: вы такая молодечка! спасибо большое! экстра спасибо за комментарий "связанные с ним последствия". это больше всего подходит к конкексту того отрывка, который анализирую. спасибо! вопрос: в придаточном предложении простой союз "что" + глагол в л-форме + "бы", и не отделенныи друг от друга союз "чтобы"?

Answer (score 0):

Никак не надо "интерпретировать". Здесь нет ни сослагательного, ни условного наклонения в чистом виде.
Это некая модальность, что ли... Виртуальная, если позволено будет так выразится. А грамматически - обычная фраза сложноподчиненное предложение. 
"Представьте, что..." "Вообразите, что...", "Допустим, что..." и т. д.

Просто опустите частицу "бы" - она здесь совершенно лишняя. Можно, впрочем, в контексте считать её усилительной частицей, но это некий разговорный вариант, даже просторечный, вариант, грамматически далеко не идеальный.

И я повторяю свой давний совет. Эти вещи хорошо изложены в "Корпусной грамматике", читайте там. Как раз на ваш уровень дотошности и формальности.

http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5